# Access to WordPress upload directory through url is showing 403 error message

Tags: wordpress

I have an application in WordPress where I have saved a pdf file to the `wp-content/uploads/ccroipr-pdf/` folder.

**The code is something like that to create and save the PDF file:**

```
$upload         = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_dir     = $upload['basedir'];
$upload_dir     = $upload_dir . '/ccroipr-pdf/';

if (! is_dir($upload_dir)) {
    mkdir( $upload_dir, 0700 );
}        

$filename= $confirm_id.'.pdf';      
$pdf->Output($upload_dir.$filename,'F');
```

Now when I access the file using this URL:

http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/ccroipr-pdf/ccroipr-20200511090236163.pdf

It's showing me 403 error message?

Is that for the directory permission? If so then which permission I should write for the download only?

Comment: There will be better security people than me so there is probably a more definitive answer but, if change the folder and the file to 755, not 700.  The folder being 755 would probably do it, so try that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended file permissions for wordpress folders is `0755` not `0700` -

The owner is your `user` on the server or your `apache` name, not the user of your site.

So changing the permission to `0700` will not make it download only, but rather so that all guests to the site can't even access the files to download them at all.

Comment: So you mean for register user I should use `0755` and for everyone `0700`?

Comment: I mean, if you don't use `0755` the files are not accessible to other users of your server.

Comment: If your application is using mpdf. You could try using this https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setdisplaymode.html and set to `$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('none');`

Comment: Got it. I am using TCPDF.

Comment: Try `$pdf->Output("filename.pdf",'D');`

Comment: Is there any issue with `F` ?

Comment: I don't see why not.  If that works to what you want to do.

Comment: FYI, that pdf file is generated using jQuery/ Ajax call. So If I use `D` it's not saving the PDF file to the folder.

Comment: I've only worked with MPDF, i just looked at possible solutions for the output with TCPDF.